# TableList becomes crashing when i push back from Details page to TableList page in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I have created a tableList when I get a response from server I am creating a tableList and displaying tableList data and when I tap on TableList I am going to Details page so for everything is fine.

The problem is when I push back from Details page to TableList view an then when I scroll tableList I am getting an Exception like NSRage exception like empty array.

### code:-

```
@interface StockEnquiryVC () {

    NSMutableArray * BatchNoArray,*QtyArray,*DeptArray,*LocationArray,*MainArray;
}
@end

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        BatchNoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        QtyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        DeptArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        LocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }

        -(void)PostCallService1:(id)mainDictyionary{

         if([ mainDictyionary count ] == 0){
                   NSLOg(@"No data Available")
                }else{

                //calling TableList:-
                [self CreateTableList];
             }
        }

        -(void)CreateTableList{

            MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 102, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height - 102)  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            MaintableView.delegate = self;
            MaintableView.dataSource = self;
            MaintableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            MaintableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            MaintableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            [MaintableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
            [MaintableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
            [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];
            MaintableView.backgroundColor = [BG colorWithHexString:@"FFB848"];
        }

        //TableList Delegate methods:-

        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

            return BatchNoArray.count;
        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
            StackLedgerCell *cell = (StackLedgerCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackLedgerCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.batchLabel.text = [BatchNoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.qtyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",[[QtyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue]];
            cell.departmentLabel.text = [DeptArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.locationLabel.text = [LocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the error from Console ?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: i am getting this eroor

Comment: You should go to XCode -> Add all exception to check what array is empty

Comment: And post the code that you declare BatchNoArray, DeptArray, LocationArray

Comment: in view didload i allocate them

Comment: How do you return from the detail view?

Comment: this BatchNoArray and QtyArray,*DeptArray,*LocationArray,*MainArray; becomes empty when i back from details list that s why i am getting this exception

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 i updated my code please see once and plese guide me

Comment: Try to NSLog all array and their count value and put that code of initializing your array when you getting response from server...

Comment: I can't see the code where you dismiss the detail controller. Make sure you aren't pushing s new instance of your table view controller

Answer (score 0):

Do you changing array in detail view controller? Use

> [MaintableView reloadData]

in viewDidappear when navigating back

Comment: this BatchNoArray and QtyArray,*DeptArray,*LocationArray,*MainArray; becomes empty when i back from details list that s why i am getting this exception

Comment: Can you post all code pls ?  code of when you navigate back from vc.